# meteor routers dont attach the events to the dom nodes

Tags: meteor, iron-router

my twbs:bootstrap or spectrum:material-design-lite JS is not working when i use it inside routed (using iron:router) module. All twbs:bootstrap or spectrum:material-design-lite JS functionalities work fine via non-router path. Anyone has any idea, why is this happening?
CSS is loaded fine all the time but JS events are not attached when going via router.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Please elaborate your question and show us what have you tried so far.

Comment: I just installed it in my project folder using "spectrum:material-design-lite". Then pasted the markup inside my module.<template name="hello"> <form action="#">
  <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label textfield-demo">
    <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="sample3" />
    <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="sample3">Text...</label>
  </div>
</form></template> and called this 'hello' template for the '/hello' path using the router. This markup has some floating effect that uses MDL JS. This does not work in this router case.

Comment: But if i add the same markup inside 'main.html' that is not called thro' router, i get to see the floating effect appear on the screen.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31382590/material-design-lite-layout-has-changed-after-installing-ironrouter/31386468#31386468


Refer to this link duplicate question

Comment: The solution is here https://forums.meteor.com/t/material-design-lite/6553/11?u=nobso