# Material Design Lite layout has changed after installing Iron:router

Tags: meteor, iron-router, material-design-lite

I created a meteor project and added krazyeom:material-design-lite package. Then I created 2 simple html files, one that contains

```
<head>...</head>
```

and another that contains

```
<body>...</body>
```

My design looks something like this:

[image: Layout with full-height menu]

After I added the iron:router and only replaced `<body>` with `<template name="layout">` and `</body>` with `</template>`.

```
Router.route('/', {name: 'layout'});
```

It looks like this:

[image: Broken layout with non full-height menu]

As you can see the design is now not 100% height; and if I resize to mobile resolution, it doesn't appear the 3 lines icon to show the sidebar.

What could be the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i had the same issues.As of now there is some issues while using mdl with iron router . Even there are issues with Template.xyz.events not firing with mdl custom tags .

This issues will be resloved soon (Hope so)

https://github.com/Zodiase/meteor-mdl

This repo is under active development in supporting mdl in meteor . Please follow this repo for any advancement.

Other wise use similar addon like https://atmospherejs.com/materialize/materialize

which does the material design like mdl and i am using it for couple of my project and have no issues

Comment: Thanks. I will use materialize. I hope that materialize will not die after material design appearing.